# macOS Calendar stuck at "Updating calendars..."

Tags: macos, mac, icloud, calendar, ical

I launched the Mac Calendar app, only to see no calendars or events.

I quit the app, but on restart it now shows "Updating calendars..." and a never-ending progress bar...

[image: Updating Calendars...]

Quitting the app doesn't work. Force Quitting the app does close it, but the progress bar is displayed at the next startup as well.

How can I move past this screen and update my calendars?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using AppCleaner to remove the cached files for the Calendar app.

https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/

That works for me.